# How set orderby term_id on get_the_terms() value on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code:

```php
$term_obj_list = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'entry_parametrs' );
```

How can I set `orderby` in array result for sort by `term_id` desc?

Comment: You should be able to use [`wp_get_post_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/) instead which does [support ordering](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/). Note that that function is not cached so if you call it frequently on a single request, it might bog you down. The alternative is to just use one of [PHP's built in array sorts](https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms(
        $post->ID,   //POST ID
        'post_tag', //Taxonomy name
        array( 'order' => 'DESC' )  //order Args     
    );
```

You will get all terms by term ID in DESC order on the above Object.